# Nesting foreach, how to be more efficient

Tags: php, performance, for-loop, foreach

First of all, hello
I'm currently making a report system who does take 6 fields(6 selects, all of them being multiples).

I receive their input as a array, and i need process each value for each field

For example, let's give the fields A, B and C.

The field A have the values [1, 2, 3].

The field B have the values [4,5,6].

The field C have the values [7,8,9].

I need make the code run and return like this

```
1-4-7
1-4-8
1-4-9
1-5-7
1-5-8
1-5-9
( And so on )
```

Actually, i'm doing this by nesting several foreach's, but i believe it is inefficient(i'm taking almost 30 to 35 seconds to do the loop(without consider the MySQL Query i do inside it)

Does exists a more efficient way to do this?

EDIT

As requested on the comments, i got a example

```
// I'm ignoring SQL Injection since it is a example only
$status = explode("-", $_POST['status']);
$type = explode("-", $_POST['type']);
$store = explode("-", $_POST['store']);

foreach($status as $statusKey => $statusID) {
    foreach($type as $typeKey => $typeID) {
        foreach($store as $storeKey => $storeID) {
            echo $statusID." - ".$typeID." - ".$storeID.PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you try to rephrase this problem by writing a function that takes n fields and returns all the results? That way it might be easier to try to think about an optimization.

Comment: what you have done so far, is there any code you can share with which you are facing issue?

Comment: So you have 6 sets of data from the database and then you need to cross join them, is that right? Does anything else happen in the code? Some kind of filtering, calculations, other sql queries?

Comment: The result i get i add to a table directly, so another process generate the report

Comment: How do you add it to Mysql? Do you take the output and do something with it, or do you make sql query inside of the foreach where the `echo` is in the sample?

Comment: You could create 3 temporary tables, populate them with contents of `$status`, `$type` and `$store`, then make the database do the cross join for you in `insert into... select ... a join b join c`

Comment: Where the echo is. It is a simple ``INSERT INTO table``. And it inserts the value the way it gets(since the input is an array of id's). I've discarded the possibility of being the SQL too slow, after i commented and substituted it with a simple echo. Yet the code kept slow.

Comment: I'll try the Temporary Tables, i give feedback if it actually works or no

Comment: Also, when you insert date to temporary tables, use the advice from Damian's answer. Sql queries in the loop are highly inefficient. It's much faster if you prepare one big insert with all the data and call the database only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to prepare a statement in the loops and execute it outside of the loops, so you will have something like this:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

More here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html

Without INSERT this code should be super fast as this are very basic operations.